# Expectation using survival function formula?

Tags: probability

I think my textbook has an error in the worked solutions, but I want to double check I just don't misunderstand.

Let $X_i$ be a random variable such that $P(X_i \geq x ) = e/x\log x$ for $x \geq e$

We know that if $X \geq 0$ then $E[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X\geq x)dx$

Now, the textbook gives the answer as

$$E[X] = \int_e^\infty e/x\log x \space dx$$

However, surely using the above formula it should actually be

$$E[X] = e+ \int_e^\infty e/x\log x \space dx$$

Since $P(X > y) = 1$ for $y \in [0,e]$?

Or am I misunderstanding something basic here?

Edit:

The fact $E[X]$ is infinite doesn't matter, as the question does the same for the truncated variables $E[X 1_{(|X|\leq n)}]$

Comment: Where does the summand $e$ in your calculation come from?

Comment: What is the name of the survival function?

Comment: $E(X)$ does not converge. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_e%5E%5Cinfty+e%2Fx*log(x)+dx)

Comment: I know it does not converge, But supposing for a moment it did.... Since this working does the same for the truncated variable (which does converge)

Comment: @J.Wang from integrating $P(X > y)=1$ from $0$ to $e$